# Speeding up matplotlib voxels by skipping zero elements in 3D array

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, voxel

I'm trying to plot 3D voxels using matplotlib. My array is always 256x256x256 zeros with some elements set to 1. I am testing with just the middle elements set to 1 (see code below).

I can change the voxelarray size to 100x100x100 to test and it takes 20 seconds, but 256x256x256 takes over 5 minutes (and my application requires this size). I would love to just plot the nonzero elements and not force matplotlib to iterate over every empty voxel. I tried using np.nonzero but the output is not 3D so it cannot be plotted. Is there a way to speed this up?

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

voxelarray = np.zeros((256,256,256))
voxelarray[127:128, 127:128, 127:128] = 1

start_time = time.process_time()

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ax.voxels(voxelarray)

ax.set_xlim([0,256])
ax.set_ylim([0,256])
ax.set_zlim([0,256])
ax.set_xlabel('0 - Dim')
ax.set_ylabel('1 - Dim')
ax.set_zlabel('2 - Dim')

final_time = time.process_time() - start_time
print(final_time) ```
````

Comment: I looked into this a bit today, so not a full answer. **1)** If you don't need it to look pretty you can disable shadows / shading, `ax.voxels(voxelarray,shade=None)`. This gave my use case a ~50% speed improvement. **2)** If you don't need the axis + labels and other matplotlib features it will be faster to use something else. **3)** If matplotlib is required, I would investigate creating the polygons yourself. Basically rewrite Axes3D.voxels to your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

No you will need to iterate over all of the entries in your 3d array every time.

256^3 is 16.7 times larger than 100^3, and if the 100^3 takes 20 seconds we should expect 256^3 to take 335 seconds (5 minutes 35 seconds) if the matplotlib functions are O(n), which seems to be the case since you said it takes over 5 minutes for the 256^3.

There might be a way using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and splitting the 3d array into pieces running the figure on each of the pieces, each on separate threads and then stitch the plots together.

Comment: Is there another library which can do this faster? plotly can do a 3d scatterplot of the entire array in under a second but it isn't in voxels